# How can I extract text from Multiple URLs using beautifulsoup?

Tags: web-scraping

I am doing lead generation and want to extract text for a handful of URLs. Here is my code to extract for one URL. What should i do if i want to extract for more than one URL and save it into a dataframe?

```
import urllib
from urllib.request import urlopen as urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup



url = 'https://www.wdtl.com/'
html = urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)


for script in soup(["script", "style"]):
script.extract()    # rip it out

text = soup.get_text()
lines = (line.strip() for line in text.splitlines())
chunks = (phrase.strip() for line in lines for phrase in line.split("  "))
text = '\n'.join(chunk for chunk in chunks if chunk)

print(text)
```

Comment: there is a lot of _fluff_ in terms of links on that page. What sorts of links are you actually after off the page?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you can get there using this simplified method. Let's see if it works for you:

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests
headers={'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'}
url = 'https://www.wdtl.com/'

resp = requests.get(url,headers = headers)
soup = bs(resp.content, "lxml")

#first, find the links
links = soup.find_all('link',href=True)

#create a list to house the links
all_links= []

#find each link and add it to the list
for link in links:
    if 'http' in link['href']: #the soup contains many non-http links; this will remove them
        all_links.append(link['href'])

#finally, load the list into a dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(all_links)
```